# Periodic or not Periodic signal

Tags: signal

I am trying to solve following problem which I try to find the signal is periodic or not.

[image]

However, as it is different from traditional examples I do not know how to solve it. Can you please give me clues or solve it?

Comment: Do you know the (formal) definition of a periodic signal?

Comment: Yes I know the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***If a signal is periodic then its derivative will also be periodic***

So $$x(t)=sin((\sqrt{2t}+5)+sin(\pi t))-1$$ its derivative is 
$$x'(t)=\frac{cos((\sqrt{2t}+sin(\pi t)+5))}{\sqrt{2t}}+\pi cos(\pi t)cos((\sqrt2t+sin(\pi t)+5))$$

$$x'(t)=x_1(t)+x_2(t)$$
where \$x_1(t)=\frac{cos((\sqrt{2t}+sin(\pi t)+5))}{\sqrt{2t}}\$ and \$x_2(t)=\pi cos(\pi t)cos((\sqrt2t+sin(\pi t)+5))\$
Now \$x_1(t)\$ is **aperiodic** because [wolframalpha result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20t%20tends%20to%20infinity%20cos((%E2%88%9A2t%2Bsin(%CF%80t)%2B5))%2F%E2%88%9A2t)
$$\lim_{t \to \infty}\frac{cos((\sqrt{2t}+sin(\pi t)+5))}{\sqrt{2t}}=0$$

Now $$x_2(t)=\pi cos(\pi t)cos((\sqrt2t+sin(\pi t)+5))$$
$$x_2(t)=\frac{\pi}{2}{[cos((\pi t-\sqrt2t-sin(\pi t)-5))+cos((\pi t+\sqrt2t+sin(\pi t)+5))]}$$

Now \$x_2(t)\$ can also be checked with above property of derivative individually that will come as aperiodic signal

So \$x'(t)\$ is sum of two aperiodic signal that will be a aperiodic signal.

Hence \$x(t)\$ is aperiodic signal

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I ask you another little question?

Comment: @NihadAzimli Yes Please

Comment: if our T1 and T2 is pi/something how can we find T0. Because LCM(T1,T2)/HCF(T1,T2) is not working for this example since we have to get integer for LCM and HCF

Comment: @NihadAzimli I think you can't do with that method because what \$T\$ you will take for \$sin((\sqrt{2t}+5)\$ this signal itself is aperiodic.same like asking what will be the period(\$T\$) of \$e^t\$

Comment: Are you sure that this derivative is correct?  The second sin is in the first sin.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives d/dt(sin((sqrt(2 t) + 5) + sin(π t)) - 1) = (1/(sqrt(2) sqrt(t)) + π cos(π t)) cos(sqrt(2) sqrt(t) + sin(π t) + 5)

Comment: -1 -- the derivative is simply wrong

Comment: @ScottSeidman sorry sir I just thought the bracket term is not in whole  of sine term.....corrected it... and Thanks..still learning :-)

Comment: took back the downvote -- but you would need to formally demonstrate that the derivative is aperiodic for an upvote.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Please check